# how can I delete a entered text in sharedpreference with onclick

Tags: java, android, onclick, sharedpreferences

How can I delete a saved text in sharedpreference with onclick method ? If i enter something in my activity and save it in my second activity I can click on it, but i can't delete it.
So for example: I write some names, rudolf, harry, gandalf and i want to delete the name harry if i click on him.

Here's the whole code:

```
enter code here RecyclerView recyclerView;
                SharedPreferences preferences;
                JSONObject saved;
                ViewGroup viewGroup;



                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_dinner2);



                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("dinner");
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



                recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);




               preferences = getSharedPreferences("text", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
               Log.d("Testing", preferences.getString("saved", ""));
               try {
               saved = new JSONObject(preferences.getString("saved", ""));
               } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               }

               final RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new 
               LinearLayoutManager(Dinner2Activity.this);
               recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
               recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter());

               }


               public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.Holder> {

               public Adapter() {
               }

              @NonNull
              @Override
              public Adapter.Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
              View view = LayoutInflater.from(Dinner2Activity.this).inflate(R.layout.row_item, 
              viewGroup, false);
              Holder holder = new Holder(view);
              view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
              SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("text", MODE_PRIVATE);
              preferences.edit().remove("").commit();



             }
             });
             return holder;
             }



             @Override
             public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.Holder holder, int position) {
             try {
             holder.textView.setText(saved.getString("saved" + position));
             } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
            return saved.length();
            }

            public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView textView;

            public Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);

            }

            }

            }

            }

                here's the onclick:

enter code here @NonNull
                @Override
                public Adapter.Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(Dinner2Activity.this).inflate(R.layout.row_item, 
                viewGroup, false);
                Holder holder = new Holder(view);
                view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("text", MODE_PRIVATE);
                preferences.edit().remove("").commit();



               }
               });
               return holder;
               }
```

Comment: You may invalidate your adapter.
I can find code for updating adapter after removing

Comment: How can I do this ?

Comment: use the method notifyDataSetInvalidated() in your adapter. You should call it after removing item.
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter#notifyDataSetInvalidated()

Comment: Right. Now the text is moving if I click it, but it's not deleted.

Comment: SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("text", MODE_PRIVATE);
              preferences.edit().remove(**"Key"**).commit();
Please, put the correct key instead of empty string

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("DataStorage", 0);
preferences.edit().remove("keyOfprefToRemove").commit();
```

Comment: shared preferences store data inform of key/value pairs. if you have a key in it which  you have named "person1" and assigned it the value "gandalf"...to remove the value gandalf you just get a reference of the sharedpreference like above and inside the remove() you put gandalf's key. In this case from my example, you would put "person1"